# Calling a Borland DLL from Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, borland-c++

Is it possible for python 2.5 to load a Borland Builder DLL, and call functions within the DLL?

We have an old application written with Borland Builder (we have the full source, but porting it to Visual Studio is a long term goal), and we need to add some new tests to this.

All of the code we actually need to test is in a DLL, and I presume that we can use `ctypes` to access this, but will there be clashes between the Borland run time amd the MSVC run times?

Comment: Probably @DavidHeffernan can answer this. ctypes supports cdecl and stdcall, but not fastcall if that's used. You may need to manually decorate cdecl exports with an underscore. Don't mix `FILE` streams between runtimes, and file descriptors are specific to a runtime. Also, `free` memory using the same CRT that was used to `malloc` it.